# How to create a label with QGIS project path in print composer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, file-path

Is there a way in the Print Composer of QGIS to create a label that will automatically update the path of the QGIS project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Insert a label, and for the label text insert an expression with the text: `@project_path`

The @project_path variable is automatically filled with the current path  of the project.

Comment: Hi, again. If I put **'@project_path'** in print composer appears @project_path ando if I put **@project_path** an expression error appears.  I'm sorry about my level, I've been looking for some help about expressions in QGIS but I didn't get it.

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: QGIS 2.8.2 because is a LTR and I have some problems to install software. I work in a public administration and I've no permission for install newer versions :-(

Comment: The expression variables were introduced in 2.10, so you'll need to wait for the next LTR to have access to them

Comment: I'm closing this as duplicate of an older question which has a solution before @project_path was introduced.